# Visual Studio Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect

Im tryin to setup a kinect app, i did the channel9 tutorial

Now im facing a problem that cannot use my hand within the app. The kinect doesn't not recognize my skeleton/won't turn green.

i used the following code :

```
  using App14.Common;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Xaml.Controls;
using WindowsPreview.Kinect;



// The Grid App template is documented at 

namespace App14
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton Application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
        protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {

#if DEBUG
            // Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // Display the current frame rate counters
                this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
            }
#endif

            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active

            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();
                //Associate the frame with a SuspensionManager key                                
                SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "AppFrame");
                // Set the default language
                rootFrame.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    // Restore the saved session state only when appropriate
                    try
                    {
                        await SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();
                    }
                    catch (SuspensionManagerException)
                    {
                        //Something went wrong restoring state.
                        //Assume there is no state and continue
                    }
                }

                KinectRegion kinectRegion = new KinectRegion();
                KinectUserViewer KinectUserViewer = new KinectUserViewer()
                {
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                    Height = 100,
                    Width = 121,
                };
                Grid grid = new Grid();

                grid.Children.Add(kinectRegion);
                grid.Children.Add(KinectUserViewer);
                kinectRegion.Content = rootFrame;


                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = grid;
            }
            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage), e.Arguments);
            }
            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
        /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
        /// of memory still intact.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
        private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            await SuspensionManager.SaveAsync();
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

When i launch the app i get the following output code :

```
    'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsPreview.Kinect.8.1_2.0.1410.19000_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsPreview.Kinect.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Debug\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Globalization.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Collections\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Collections.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Foundation.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ObjectModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ObjectModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Storage.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Data.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.IO.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App14.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[9472] App14.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Anyone help? im stuck the whole day with this :) thanks

Comment: Btw Hi Guys! im new @ stackoverflow

Comment: Use Kinect Studio (from Kinect SDK) to connect with your app while it is running, it's useful for debugging what the camera sees. Also, I'm not sure about v2, but v1 needs to detect a full skeleton, not only your hand.

Comment: can you please share the link of the tutorial, I've practiced their tutorial, which one you are working on?

Comment: Hi Rafaf!

AAAH Thanks for your reaction!!! !https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Programming-Kinect-for-Windows-v2/03 This is the link!

Comment: i Have the kinect v2 by the way

Comment: @ Wouter Huysentruit the kinect studio for the v2 don't support that?

Comment: This is my GroupedItemsPage.xaml

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/document_1